# PBI exponential number

Tags: powerbi, dax

Why in Power BI reports i got thoose numbers, on zeroes values existing in table? No agregations only Sum()

> Clustered Bar Chart

[image]

Comment: what kind of visual is that? It has a horizontal axis with  markers for 0.0M and 0.2M, so it is not a table.

Comment: Clustered Bar Chart

Comment: So, your question says you're using a table. What does the data look like in a table?? Change the format of the measure to reveal the real number. Without seeing the data that leads to the visual, it's hard to tell why your visual is showing funny things.

Comment: He means what he have zeroes in data table, but in chart got thoose values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your decimal to Fixed format

[image]